# Save new object which contains hasManyThrough relationship (Laravel,PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I have database tables and models as users and address. user may have more than one address.therefore there is a hasManyThrough relationship is mapped in the user model and there is a userAddress table for that relationship.it contains only user_id and address_id. this userAddress table has relationship for both address and user. are these mapped relationships correct?

- user model

  public function Addresses()
  {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Address', 'App\UserAddress');
  }
- address model: there is no relationship mapped on the address model
- userAddress model

  public function user()
  {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
  }

  ```
   public function address()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
   }
  ```

Following the code section, I have used to save a new address.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'address1' => 'required',
            'address2' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'postalCode' => 'required',
        ]);

        $address = new Address();
        $address->address = $request->address1;
        $address->address_2 = $request->address2;
        $address->city = $request->city;
        $address->postcode = $request->postalCode;
        $address->save();
further I have used boot f
```

untion(in userAddress model) to save user_id and address_id in userAddress table as follows

```
 protected static function boot(){

        parent::boot();

        Address::created(function($address) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if (!empty($user)){
                $userAddress = new UserAddress();
                $userAddress->user()->associate($user);
                $userAddress->address()->associate($address);
                $userAddress->save();
            }
        });
    }
```

is this code correct or no?

Comment: It sounds like you have a `hasMany` relationship; users have many addresses. This would mean that the `userAddress` model class is not necessary, because it is not necessary to create a model class for the pivot table.

Comment: yes. I have save data using the relationship with the address table